# How to change Magento2 export product MULTI VALUE SEPARATOR?

Tags: csv

In product import, there is interface input box to select multi value separator which is comma.

But in product export, we cannot select separator so it will mix up with the field separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Export/Product.php , you will find something like:

```
$dataRow['additional_images'] =
                implode(Import::DEFAULT_GLOBAL_MULTI_VALUE_SEPARATOR, $additionalImages);
            $dataRow['additional_image_labels'] =
                implode(Import::DEFAULT_GLOBAL_MULTI_VALUE_SEPARATOR, $additionalImageLabels);
```

Which means Magento handles multi value rows using a global constant  Import::DEFAULT_GLOBAL_MULTI_VALUE_SEPARATOR , which is shared among import & export.

To simply change it, you can change the constant in vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import.php:

```
/**
 * default delimiter for several values in one cell as default for FIELD_FIELD_MULTIPLE_VALUE_SEPARATOR
 */
const DEFAULT_GLOBAL_MULTI_VALUE_SEPARATOR = '|';
```

Comment: Moreover, for multi values it reuses the same constant, so you have to double check collectMultiselectValues() in  vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Export/Product.php and change Import::DEFAULT_GLOBAL_MULTI_VALUE_SEPARATOR to "comma" otherwise the saved attribute value will not get parsed correctly

Comment: Hi, I've modified the file, run setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, static-content:deploy, and cleared the caches but still the files come up with the comma separator. Am I missing something?